# Java - Counting the vowels in string

Tags: java, string, for-loop, charat

The code below is supposed to count the syllables in a string based upon the following principles:

1. It should count a single vowel or a set of vowels as a syllable.
2. If a lone "e" is at the end of the string and there is more of vowels in the rest of the string, then "e" is not a syllable.
3. If a lone "e" is at the end, and there is one or more vowels next to "e" and there is also more vowels in the rest of the string, then "e" is a syllable.

My code does the first two rules but not the last one. Can someone help me modify this code in a way that the 3rd rule is fulfilled as well?

```
protected int countSyllables(String word) {
    String input = word.toLowerCase();
    int syl = 0;
    boolean  vowel  = false;
    int length = word.length();
    //check each word for vowels (don't count more than one vowel in a row)
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if        (isVowel(input.charAt(i)) && (vowel==false)) {
            vowel = true;
            syl++;
        } else if (isVowel(input.charAt(i)) && (vowel==true)) {
            vowel = true;
        } else {
            vowel = false;
        }
    }
    char tempChar = input.charAt(input.length()-1);
    //check for 'e' at the end, as long as not a word w/ one syllable
    if ((tempChar == 'e')  && (syl != 1)) {
        syl--;
    }
    return syl;
}
```

Comment: before subtracting `syl--` you must first check there is not a vowel in the previous character.

Comment: Could you give us an example of valid input and output for the 2nd and third case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected int countSyllables(String word) {
    if(word.isEmpty()) return 0; //don't bother if String is empty

    word = word.toLowerCase();
    int      totalSyllables    = 0;
    boolean  previousIsVowel  = false;
    int      length = word.length();

    //check each word for vowels (don't count more than one vowel in a row)
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        //create temp variable for vowel
        boolean isVowel = isVowel(word.charAt(i));

        //use ternary operator as it is much simple (condition ? true : false)
        //only increments syllable if current char is vowel and previous is not
        totalSyllables += isVowel && !previousIsVowel ? 1 : 0;

        if(i == length - 1) { //if last index to allow for 'helloe' to equal 2 instead of 1
            if (word.charAt(length - 1) == 'e' && !previousIsVowel)
                totalSyllables--; //who cares if this is -1
        }

        //set previousVowel from temp 
        previousIsVowel = isVowel;
    }

    //always return 1 syllable
    return totalSyllables > 0 ? totalSyllables : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a condition before removing a syllable when testing if a `e` is at the end. Just make sure the character at one character from the end is not a vowel.

---

### Solution

```
if ((tempChar == 'e')  && (syl != 1) && !isVowel(word.charAt(word.length()-2))) {
    syl--;
}
```

---

### Output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countSyllables("Canoe"));  // 2
    System.out.println(countSyllables("Bounce")); // 1
    System.out.println(countSyllables("Free"));   // 1
}
```

Comment: @LalehH Glad to help ! Do not forget to upvote if it helped you in any way :)